# Lucene Get The Score From a Search

Tags: .net, lucene.net

Brand new to Lucence
How do I get the score from a search?
This is the format of the search
I saw an example of how to get Score from an ScoreDocs[] array but I want to put it in the class SampleData

```
private static SampleData _mapLuceneDocumentToData(Document doc)
{
    return new SampleData
    {
        sID = Convert.ToInt32(doc.Get("sID")),
        Text = doc.Get("Text")
        //Name = doc.Get("Name"),
        //Description = doc.Get("Description")
    };
}
private static IEnumerable<SampleData> _mapLuceneToDataList(IEnumerable<Document> hits)
{
    return hits.Select(_mapLuceneDocumentToData).ToList();
}
private static IEnumerable<SampleData> _mapLuceneToDataList(IEnumerable<ScoreDoc> hits, IndexSearcher searcher)
{
    return hits.Select(hit => _mapLuceneDocumentToData(searcher.Doc(hit.Doc))).ToList();
}
private static Query parseQuery(string searchQuery, QueryParser parser)
{
    Query query;
    try
    {
        query = parser.Parse(searchQuery.Trim());
    }
    catch (ParseException)
    {
        query = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(searchQuery.Trim()));
    }
    return query;
}
private static IEnumerable<SampleData> _search (string searchQuery, string searchField = "")
{
    // validation
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery.Replace("*", "").Replace("?", ""))) 
        return new List<SampleData>();

    // set up lucene searcher
    using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(_directory, false))
    {
        var hits_limit = 1000;
        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);

        // search by single field
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchField))
        {
            var parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, searchField, analyzer);
            var query = parseQuery(searchQuery, parser);
            var hits = searcher.Search(query, hits_limit).ScoreDocs;
            var results = _mapLuceneToDataList(hits, searcher);
            analyzer.Close();
            searcher.Dispose();
            return results;  return results;
```

Answer (score 2):

the score is in the hits but not in the Document
the answer was

```
private static SampleData _mapLuceneDocumentScoreToData(Document doc, float score)
{
    SampleData sampleData = new SampleData
    {
        sID = Convert.ToInt32(doc.Get("sID")),
        Text = doc.Get("Text"),
        Score = score
    };
}
private static IEnumerable<SampleData> _mapLuceneToDataList(IEnumerable<ScoreDoc> hits, IndexSearcher searcher)
{
    return hits.Select(hit => _mapLuceneDocumentScoreToData(searcher.Doc(hit.Doc), hit.Score)).ToList();
}
```